# parameter of type (int) -> Void

Tags: xcode, swift

I've been working with NSOpenPanel and I stumbled upon the `beginSheetModalForWindow` function.

It asks 2 parameters, namely one of type NSWindow and one of type (Int) -> Void.

I know the NSWindow class, but the second one I don't understand. Any help?

Comment: The second param is a `closure` https://www.weheartswift.com/closures/

Answer (score 1):

It is a closure function. Example usage would be:

```
beginSheetModalForWindow(window : NSWindow) { (int) -> Void in
    // Your code 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That second parameter defines what your app does after the user has made a selection:

```
let panel = NSOpenPanel()
panel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.window) { result in
    guard result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton else {
        // The user clicked Cancel, there's nothing to do
        // May be display a warning or something
        return
    }

    // Get the file's address
    let url = panel.URL!

    // Now open the file or do whatever you want with it
}
```